# How to set default value for HTML drop-down list not from the option element?

Tags: html

I'm using an adaptation of PHPBB to create a drop-down list.

```
  <select name="destination_path">
    <!-- BEGIN path -->
    <option value="{path.DESCRIPTION}">{path.DESCRIPTION}</option>
    <!-- END path -->
  </select>
```

The list is generated from a MySQL query, so it is dynamic. This list is within a form and when the form is fired I want to retain (and return) it's state in session variables. My first thought was to place something in the `<select>` statement.

I  know you can use:

```
selected="option_selected"
```

in the relevant `<option>`, but it seems like a messy way to do this and would require an if statement to compare each tag as the tag is created.

***Is there a way to declare the default option in the select tag, or a better defined method to achieve the same result?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The `select` tag defines the selected option in its `option` elements. What you could do if you want to achieve it differently, is putting the selected option on top without specifying a `selected` attribute. Most browsers select the first option as default if there is no `selected` attribute present.

```
Ex :
 <select>
 <option value="Hi"> Hi </option>
 <option value="Hello" selected> Hello </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: That would work, but would it not affect the order the list is presented?

Comment: @blarg Yes, it would.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to select the option you need after compiling the list by adding a little jQuery.

A similar question has been asked on the [jQuery Forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-dynamically-select-option-in-dropdown-menu).

Using the example of:

```
<select name="options">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Green</option>
  <option value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

You can set the selected option by value:

```
$('[name=options]').val( 3 ); // To select Blue
```

Or you can set the selected option using the text:

```
$('[name=options] option').filter(function() { 
    return ($(this).text() == 'Blue'); //To select Blue
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Links to jsFiddle can be found in [this post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-dynamically-select-option-in-dropdown-menu#14737000003469469).

Credit to: [Godsbest](http://forum.jquery.com/user/godsbest) on the jQuery Forums.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes....** there is a way to declare the default option in the select tag

Try this...

To set a default value first you have to mention the **name** of the **select** tag and in the **find**(**)** function just pass the **value** you have to set as **default** value.

```
$('select[name="destination_path"]').find('option:contains("default")')
.attr("selected",true);
```

Comment: Please, care to add some comment or explanation. Pasting just a few lines of code isn't to warm welcome here.